# Setup Monero mining pool using mpos

Tags: monerod, blockchain, mining-pools, mining

I have a problem setting up monero mining pool, I know about those nodejs pools, but I want to use MPOS as a front-end. The only problem is I don't know what to use as a stratum. 

I haven't even found any guide for monero, only github project that show how to do it.

I would really appreciate it if someone could send me to right direction, if anyone here has already tried that and succeeded.

Proof that it can be done is:

- https://monero.miningpoolhub.com/
- https://xmr.blockquarry.com/
- https://xmr.suprnova.cc/